# warning while trying to display google ads

Tags: android

I am trying to display my google ads and i am doing it in oncreate method.

here is what i am doing.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cities);



        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a150cb2e3184cd");
        LinearLayout addLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addlay);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        // adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        addLay.addView(adView);
        adRequest.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when i am running my application i am getting the following warning and screen transition is slow.

here is the warning

```
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #4'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:859)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at c.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at c.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-20 05:07:22.952: W/webview_proxy(8998):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

here is my AsyncTask class

```
public class CityData extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (!lstresponse.isEmpty()) {
                    lstresult.addAll(lstresponse);
                    lstcities.setAdapter(CustAdapter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SendRequesttoServer();
            return "1";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

    }
```

what is the mistake i am doing??..

Thanks:)

Comment: Your error showing that there is an issue in `AsyncTask` where is that code ?

Comment: @Grishu i am not displaying google ads in AsyncTask. In AsyncTask i am performing a method consuming but displaying google ads i am doing in oncreate method only

Comment: Remove async task and try the GoogleAds Working or not.?

Comment: I did not say that you are displaying ads in asynctask i just asked your for the code of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @Grishu ok grishu. i am sorry:).. i have added AyncTask class.

Comment: Is this method `SendRequesttoServer();` contains code for loading `WebView` ?

Comment: @Grishu it's just a listview. but i am trying to call soap response.. which is communicating to server

Comment: I think your `doInBackground` method contains the code for interaction with `WebView` that is why its throwing error `A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #4'.`

Comment: @Grishu i looked into some blog. they explained like if u  performing consuming a method, it's better to perform in AyncTask class. so i did it in AsyncTask

Comment: @Grishu but if i remove google ads i will not get that warning

Comment: Is there any child already added in your `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26509/discussion-between-user2143817-and-grishu)

Comment: Check out my answer. Try out using thread as i have shown in my answer it doesn't work then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `AdView` has to do communicate over the internet and it takes time for an ad to show up.

The 'block' or 'lag' is probably the `Ad SDK's` thread trying to get an ad to show to you. I really don't think `AdMob` would block the `UI` thread while trying to get an ad, however there will be a visible delay between when you see all of your UI widget items (buttons, textfields, images, etc.) shown on the screen of your activity and when the ad shows up.

Try to load the Ads in thread as below:

> ```
>     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>       @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.main);
>           long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
>       new Thread(new Runnable() {
>       public void run() {
>         new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ID");               
>       }
>   }).start();
>  }
> ```